# PayPal Redirect Fails and Cart Is Cleared - Intermittent IE Issue

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, paypal, onepage-checkout

We seem to be having an issue similar to this one: [Redirect to Paypal emptying shopping cart](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9246/redirect-to-paypal-emptying-shopping-cart)

However I have been in touch with the poster and discussed the fix (involving the X-UA-Compatible tag) and this doesn't apply to our site.

Essentially, the customer adds items to their basket, goes through the OPC process and then clicks "Place Order". Using SagePay or gift voucher, the order proceeds as expected. Using PayPal however, around 1 time in 100 (estimated) the button greys out for 10 seconds and then the page refreshes, showing an empty basket.

This seems to have started recently (approx 1 month) and is happening intermittently. We managed to reproduce the bug once, and then cleared the cache and the complaints stopped for a few weeks. Clearing the cache regularly seems to mitigate the issue, however this is far from ideal. The bug is intermittent and as far as we can get information from the customers, is only affecting Internet Explorer.

If there is any more info that would be helpful I would be more than happy to supply it. Magento version is 1.7.0.0 and we are using PayPal Website Payments Standard. I'm aware that our version of Magento is slightly outdated and we do have plans to upgrade, however the upgrade is still a way off and we could really do with a fix for this issue now. The website address is http://www.woolwarehouse.co.uk.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps the IE aspect is a red herring... After digging around in the code I see that the redirect is handled by a block (from function redirectAction in PayPal/Controllers/StandardController.php):

`$this->getResponse()->setBody($this->getLayout()->createBlock('paypal/standard_redirect')->toHtml());`

I _think_ I remember seeing that the BLOCK_HTML cache needed refreshing the few times this has occurred but obviously I wasn't looking out for it... I'll keep an eye on the situation and update if necessary.